# Typescript Scroll window function type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a React component that will allow the user to scroll the window to the top of the screen. I've set the components and types, but I'm having trouble setting the window's properties. The current error I have is this:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

How do I properly handle the window?

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEventListener } from '../../hooks'
import { Arrow } from './styles'

interface ScrollRest {
  showBelow: number,
  className: string,
  size: string
}

interface ScrollProps {
  direction: string,
  by: number,
  to: number,
  rest: ScrollRest
}

interface ScrollFunctionProps {
  mode: string, 
  to: number
}

export default function Scroll( { direction = `up`, by, to, rest }: ScrollProps ) {
  const { showBelow, className, size = `calc(0.6em + 30px)` } = rest
  if ( ![`up`, `down`].includes( direction ) )
    throw TypeError(
      `Scroll component's direction prop must be either 'up' or 'down'`
    )
  if ( to && ( typeof to !== `number` || to <= 0 ) )
    throw TypeError( `Scroll component's to prop must be a positive number` )
  if ( by && typeof by !== `number` )
    throw TypeError( `Scroll component's by prop must be a number` )

  const [show, setShow] = useState( showBelow ? false : true )

  const scroll = ( { mode, to }: ScrollFunctionProps ) =>
    window[`scroll` + mode]( { top: to, behavior: `smooth` } ) // <- Error here!

  const handleScroll = throttle( () => {
    if ( !showBelow ) return
    if ( window.scrollY > showBelow ) {
      if ( !show ) setShow( true )
    } else {
      if ( show ) setShow( false )
    }
  }, 300 )
  useEventListener( `scroll`, handleScroll )

  const handleClick = () => {
    if ( to ) scroll( { mode: `To`, to: to * window.innerHeight } )
    else if ( by ) scroll( { mode: `By`, to: by * window.innerHeight } )
    else if ( direction === `up` ) scroll( { mode: `To`, to: 0 } )
    else scroll( { mode: `To`, to: document.body.scrollHeight } )
  }

  const arrowProps = { show, direction, className, size }
  return <Arrow onClick={handleClick} {...arrowProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change is to restrict the `mode` type to `'scrollTo' | 'scrollBy'` method names:

```
interface ScrollFunctionProps {
  mode: 'scrollTo' | 'scrollBy', 
  to: number
}
```

This allows TypeScript to correctly infer the type signatures of the `window.scrollXXX(...)` method calls.

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEventListener } from '../../hooks'
import { Arrow } from './styles'

interface ScrollRest {
  showBelow: number,
  className: string,
  size: string
}

interface ScrollProps {
  direction: string,
  by: number,
  to: number,
  rest: ScrollRest
}

interface ScrollFunctionProps {
  mode: 'scrollTo' | 'scrollBy', // restrict `mode` to known Window scroll method names
  to: number
}

export default function Scroll( { direction = `up`, by, to, rest }: ScrollProps ) {
  const { showBelow, className, size = `calc(0.6em + 30px)` } = rest
  if ( ![`up`, `down`].includes( direction ) )
    throw TypeError(
      `Scroll component's direction prop must be either 'up' or 'down'`
    )
  if ( to && ( typeof to !== `number` || to <= 0 ) )
    throw TypeError( `Scroll component's to prop must be a positive number` )
  if ( by && typeof by !== `number` )
    throw TypeError( `Scroll component's by prop must be a number` )

  const [show, setShow] = useState( showBelow ? false : true )

  const scroll = ( { mode, to }: ScrollFunctionProps ) =>
    window[mode]( { top: to, behavior: `smooth` } )

  const handleScroll = throttle( () => {
    if ( !showBelow ) return
    if ( window.scrollY > showBelow ) {
      if ( !show ) setShow( true )
    } else {
      if ( show ) setShow( false )
    }
  }, 300 )
  useEventListener( `scroll`, handleScroll )

  const handleClick = () => {
    if ( to ) scroll( { mode: `scrollTo`, to: to * window.innerHeight } )
    else if ( by ) scroll( { mode: `scrollBy`, to: by * window.innerHeight } )
    else if ( direction === `up` ) scroll( { mode: `scrollTo`, to: 0 } )
    else scroll( { mode: `scrollTo`, to: document.body.scrollHeight } )
  }

  const arrowProps = { show, direction, className, size }
  return <Arrow onClick={handleClick} {...arrowProps} />
}
```